# Vega lite: How to change value labels

Tags: vega-lite

I could not found out way how to change labels of X axis.
I have this data and I need to show bars which have title taken from field `label`. Currently bars are aggregated by `id` and goals is to label bars with `label` even if the texts are same. I'm confused by examples what to do. Whether I should create layer or some signals. Could someone help me? IMHO this should be trivial, but I did not found anything useful.

```
      {
        "id": 15971,
        "label": "Click Next to continue",
        "result": "Success",
        "value": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 15972,
        "label": "Click Next to continue",
        "result": "No data",
        "value": 0
      },
```

[image: Current Graph]

[image: Vega editor]

Comment: Thx to jakevdp I solved it via expression and combining id + substring(datum.value,indexof(toString(datum.value), '_') + 1). Regarding inconsistency, I wanted to change UI layer, not the data layer, but I'm occasional user of Vega.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not really any way to do this in the Vega-Lite grammar, because what you want to do is semantically inconsistent: if you group values by one column, there is no guarantee that the values in another column will match within that grouping.

One option you have is to use `labelExpr` to define the desired label manually, e.g.

```json
    "x": {
      "field": "id",
      "type": "nominal",
      "axis": {"title": "x", "labelExpr": "'Click Next to continue'"},
      "scale": {"type": "point"}
    },
```